# image thumbnails are not loading [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

i have installed wordpress 4.7.5 
my PHP Version is 5.6.30

i am facing an issue, Image thumbnails are not loading on wp admin cannot see any image on media library grid view. i searched for solution but couldn't fixed it.

any help will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in your config file? This will give you some output which may point to the issue. You can do this by adding `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your wp-config.php file. Also try disabling all your plugins. If the issue goes away, re-enable them 1 by 1 until you find the plugin causing the issue.

Comment: yes i have enabled but not getting any error @PhillHealey also not in my error logs file

Answer (score 2):

My issue has been solved.
I added `extension=php_gd2.dll` in my php.ini file. and wordpress started creating thumbnails.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me too.
Debian:  apt-get install php-gd & restart apache

Comment: in case you already uploaded you images and want to avoid uploading them again you might want to use some wp plugin to regenerate your images thumbnails